# how to detect last page of pdf in html2pdf with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, html2pdf

I am working on a website which is being developed in PHP zend framework.
I need to create a pdf and i am using html2pdf for that.

Its working alright but i need to put a condition on footer content.

Like if the page is the last page then i need to show some content.

I am using this code to display page numbers.

```
<i>page [[page_cu]]/[[page_nb]]</i>
```

But how can i use it in to the condition ?

I have tried like this but m sure its wrong because its giving me an error.

```
<?php if([[page_cu]]==[[page_nb]] { ?>
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if($page_cu == $page_nb) 
{
   echo "Hello world";
}
?>
```

"Hello World" will appear only on the last page.

I've used it myself this way.